# Jquery mobile taphold and click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I have a image tag in my html. I registered two events for that image. one is onclick and another one is jquerymobie 'tabhold'. When 'taphold' is triggered, i don't want click event. But when i taphold and remove my finger from that image, click event also fired. How to restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

use tap event and not onclick event.

check this out http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: i want to call one function in onclick and another function in taphold.

Comment: then i need to call one fucntion in immediate mouseup. another one with some delay.